# Firefox won't redirect to HTTPS properly

Tags: .htaccess, url, firefox, redirect, url-rewriting

I've wrote the lines below in the .htaccess of my wordpress website, however, Firefox redirects neither http://mywebsite.com nor http://www.mywebsite.com to https://www.mywebsite.com. All the other browsers redirects properly.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Does anyone know what's the issue?

Comment: `.htaccess` doesn't listen to what browser is requesting a file unless you specify a `HTTP_USER_AGENT` .. The code that you have should work on all browsers, since it is server-side redirecting.  Have you tried clearing cache completely?  If that doesn't work, clear local DNS cache -- Furthermore .. Try Firefox on a machine that's never been to the site before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem will be solved if you disable the cache.

Comment: This is a comment and not a verifiable answer that **solves** the problem.

Comment: user "Anton Christensen" doesn't  have enough reputation to comment but try to help